# Talend: How to import this csv file in SQL?

Tags: talend

I receive CSV files from BP, regarding our fuel and tol transactions.

The file begins always with these 7 lines of information, which is not included in the details.

How can I import this data into 1 table in SQL using Talend?

I know how I can import data from a csv file into SQL, but how can I add the information in de header (Factuur number, Factuur Date, ...) to every row in de details.

```
"Factuur","12345678"
"Datum","27/02/2012"
"Totaal:","1"
"Totaal netto:","99,18"
"Totaal bruto:","107,13"
"Verzamel factuurnummer:","1234567890A"
"Valuta:","EUR"
"TXN tijd (dd/mm/jj)","TXN Nr","Kostenplaats naam","Truncated...
"11/02/2012 02:22";"00000222";"";"722222";"Truncated...
"12/02/2012 02:22";"00000223";"";"722222";"Truncated...
"13/02/2012 02:22";"00000224";"";"722222";"Truncated...
```

An imported row in SQL should look like:

```
Factuur  Datum      ...   TXT tijd        TXN Nr.   ...
12345678 27-2-2012        11-2-2012 02:22 00000222
12345678 27-2-2012        12-2-2012 02:22 00000223
```

Comment: Does the header is a fixed number of rows ? and i see two delimiters `,` and `;` !

Comment: Yes, the number of rows is always the same.
And indeed, there are 2 different delimiters. Smart ...

Comment: read file for only first 7 lines and merge these lines into a single record with factuur datum.... and put in thash...then read file in another tfileinput component and join with this thash in tmap no condition..so it will be cross join with 1 row in thash..and you get your result...   tfileinput1-->tmap--tagg--thash.....then tfileinput2---tmap (lookup thash)-->output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can store the data of the header as global variables then use them in Tmap as usual:
[image]

- TfileInputDelimited_1 : schema(key,value), separator "," and limit 7
- tJavaRow: `globalMap.put(input_row.key, input_row.value);`
- tFileInputDelimited_3 : schema(TXN_tijd, TXN_Nr, Kostenplaats_naam, ..), separator ";" and header 8
- Tmap:

[image]

And it works fine !

Comment: How can I import the 7 columns as 1 record in a separate table?

So: Read 7 rows, in tJavaRow and then output this in a SQL table.

Comment: To create one record using 7 columns, just concatenate them in a Tmap, To store data in a SQL table, replace tLogRow in the picture by a tOracleOutput or any other DBMS Output component.