# Talend: Split a data file into two flows/streams (header_info, data_rows)

Tags: talend

Please, I don't need no solution, just a few hints on how-tos. Anyhow, here is the problem I am tackeling with:

I have a file (bloomberg answer file) which is built as follows:

- we have a header part (I am only interested in the
  START-OF-FIELDS[...]END-OF-FIELDS; varying amount of fields!)
- then there is the data part: START-OF-DATA[...]END-OF-DATA. Where each row: `unique_id|some_val|some_val|EXCH_CODE|ID_BB_GLOBAL|NAME|SECURITY_TYP|TICKER\n`

Shortened example file:

```
START-OF-FILE
RUNDATE=20150921
PROGRAMFLAG=oneshot

DATEFORMAT=yyyymmdd_sep
FIRMNAME=dl111111
FILETYPE=pc
REPLYFILENAME=r150921020044_20426_01_00
SECMASTER=yes
DERIVED=yes
CREDITRISK=yes
USERNUMBER=1111111
WS=0
SN=111111
CLOSINGVALUES=yes
SECID=BB_GLOBAL
PROGRAMNAME=getdata

START-OF-FIELDS
EXCH_CODE
ID_BB_GLOBAL
NAME
SECURITY_TYP
TICKER
END-OF-FIELDS

TIMESTARTED=Mon Sep 21 01:01:18 BST 2015
START-OF-DATA
BBG004C5BLW2|0|5|LABUAN INTL FIN|BBG004C5BLW2|1MDB GLOBAL INVESTMENTS|EURO-DOLLAR|OGIMK|
BBG000MGZ064|0|5|HK|BBG000MGZ064|361 DEGREES INTERNATIONAL|Common Stock|1361|
BBG000QVRHX9|0|5|AV|BBG000QVRHX9|3BG EMCORE CONVRT GLB-A|Open-End Fund|EMBDGCA|
BBG000BP52R2|0|5|US|BBG000BP52R2|3M CO|Common Stock|MMM|
BBG0068TPTD9|0|5|TRACE|BBG0068TPTD9|51JOB INC|US DOMESTIC|JOBS|
BBG0069D1BR3|0|5|NOT LISTED|BBG0069D1BR3|51JOB INC|EURO-DOLLAR|JOBS|
BBG000BJD1D4|0|5|US|BBG000BJD1D4|51JOB INC-ADR|ADR|JOBS|
BBG008CTTWK1|0|5|FRANKFURT|BBG008CTTWK1|AABAR INVESTMENTS PJSC|EURO MTN|AABAR|
BBG008D4J9S9|0|5|FRANKFURT|BBG008D4J9S9|AABAR INVESTMENTS PJSC|EURO MTN|AABAR|
BBG008B2BXH2|0|5|SIX|BBG008B2BXH2|AARGAUISCHE KANTONALBANK|DOMESTIC|KBAARG|
BBG0016WJL30|0|5|LX|BBG0016WJL30|AB-AMERICAN INCOME PT-ATEURH|Open-End Fund|ABAATEH|
BBG006F3D598|0|5|BH|BBG006F3D598|ABBEY CAPITAL DAILY FUTURE-B|Fund of Funds|ABBDFUB|
END-OF-DATA
TIMEFINISHED=Mon Sep 21 01:03:22 BST 2015
END-OF-FILE
```

And now my questions
How can I split this file into 2 flows (field_names; data_rows)?
My problem was:

- The regex component only works on row level...
- The tFileInputMSDelimited does bring me nowhere...
- I don't want to start parsing the file by hand (tJava)... or do I have to?

Thanks for any hints in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I'd use tJavaFlex and some Java code. If you look at the actual code its not that hard to understand how it works even if you don't really know java.

Begin:

```
boolean header = false;
boolean data = false;
String headerData = "";
String line;
```

Main:

```
line = input_row.line;
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("START-OF-FIELDS") ) { header = true; }
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("END-OF-FIELDS") ) { header = false; }
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("START-OF-DATA") ) { data = true; }
if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("END-OF-DATA") ) { data = false; }

if(header && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("START-OF-FIELDS")) {
   headerData += line + "|";
}

if (data) {
  if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("START-OF-DATA")) {
   output_row.line = headerData.substring(0,headerData.length()-1); //remove the trailing delimiter.
  } else {
   output_row.line = line;
  }
} else {
   continue; //lets go to the next line.
}
```

End:

```
//if you want to handle the header separately:
globalMap.put("headerData",headerData);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was on vacation - so sorry for my late reaction. Your approach was very insightful and it seems the way to go. What I like about it most, that a new stream is created with a proper header row and if desired I could place all other header information away in the global map! Cool. Only a few changes would be necessary (init of string headerData = "ID|START|END|";

Thanks for your answer. I am now stuck with the next problem. I might find a solution (How to turn 1 row into 5 rows - flatten/normalizing the data).

Thanks once more!
Marco

Comment: Maybe you should adapt your code example somewhat: Change the "If" to "if" and the "subString" to "substring". Thanks, Marco

Comment: To split 1 row into N rows (a.k.a the other way around) you can use tJavaFlex as well, in the begin-end create a loop and in the main assign some value to it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to java code, check out this very simple job:
[image]

Generally, the header have fixed row count, so we need only to play with rows numbers:

- tFileInputDelimited1: header 11 and limit 5
- tFileInputDelimited2: header 20 and footer 3

and it works fine, if you have a dynamic rows positions, try to find these positions, save them in variables then use this job based on variables. You can also refeer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31873732/2037229).

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you add the part that figures out those numbers (header-skip, header-limit, data-skip, data-footer) it will not be more effective than Java.

Comment: I was on vacation for a week and couldn't react before - sorry for that. 
Thanks for your hint. The amount of fields varies and hence the rows are not predefined - it might even be that there are other header values (key=value) around. So this approach does not work out for me. Thanks anyway.